# Dynamic NULL removal, conversion failed but no conversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to dynamically remove all NULLS from a table. The below script worked for Money data type, but is now throwing a 'conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ProjectName to data type int' error. I don't understand what conversion it is talking about.

```
-- Get columns to remove nulls from

SELECT c.column_id,c.name,c.system_type_id,t.name as [Type]
INTO #Temp
FROM sys.columns c
     JOIN sys.types t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
     JOIN sys.tables st ON c.object_id = st.object_id 
WHERE st.name = 'Project'
AND t.name = 'varchar'--in ('int','datetime','bit','varchar')  --'money'
ORDER BY t.name--c.column_id
SELECT * FROM #Temp

--Build SQL query to update null columns to blanks   


DECLARE @CID int = 1;
DECLARE @CName nvarchar(30);
DECLARE @SQL_STRING nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @MaxCID int = (SELECT MAX(column_id) FROM #Temp)

WHILE (@CID <= @MaxCID) 
BEGIN


SET @CName = (SELECT name  FROM #Temp t WHERE @CID = t.column_id )
SET @SQL_STRING = N'UPDATE orders.Project SET ' + @CName + ' = ISNULL('+@CName+','''');'
                EXEC sp_executesql @SQL_STRING

SET @CID = (@CID + 1)
PRINT @CID + @CName
END

drop table #Temp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your print line might have a problem since CID is an Int but CNAME is an nvarchar. You can try to cast CID as nvarchar to display the concatenated output.